# Cargar Select en Laravel desde una vista

Tags: laravel, select

Bueno primero tengo mi vista principal donde tengo 2 select
uno select origen y el otro select destinos, necesito cargar algunos destinos segun el id del select origen (ya tengo el codigo jquery que me realiza la peticion ajax a una ruta y seguido del id, esta aqui todo esta bien).

en mi archivo de rutas

```
Route::get('/obtener-destinos/{idorigen}', 'WebController@obtenerDestinos');
```

Mi Controlador

```
public function obtenerDestinos($idorigen)
{
    $destinos=App\Models\Protege\Destino::all();
    $array_destinos=array();

    if($idorigen==1)
    {
        foreach ($destinos as $destino)
        {
            if($destino->id!=4)
            {
                $array_destinos=$destino;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($destinos as $destino)
        {
            if($destino->id==4)
            {
                $array_destinos=$destino;
            }
        }
    }

    $view = View::make('select-destino')->with('destinos', $array_destinos)->render();
    return response()->json(['html' => $view]);
}
```

mi vista donde genero el select Destinos

```
<select class="pl-3" style="display: flex; align-items: center; width: 80%;" id="destino" name="destino" required>
<?php $i=0; ?>
@foreach($destinos as $destino)
    @if($i==0)
        <option selected value="{{$destino->id}}">{{$destino->nombre}}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{{$destino->id}}">{{$destino->nombre}}</option>
    @endif
<?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Con esta peticion ajax cargo a mi vista del select destino

```
    <script>
$.get('/obtener-destinos/'+id_origen, function (data) {
                    $('#destino').remove();
                    $('#div_destino').html($(data.html)).fadeIn(3000);
                });
</script>
```

El error que obtengo en mi vista

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xamppnew\xampp\htdocs\viajesprotegidos\resources\views\select-destino.blade.php)
http://viajesprotegidos.yo/obtener-destinos/1
```

Comment: esa es una forma pero yo lo que hago cargo esa vista que me contiene el select. con el codigo que esta de ultimo.

Comment: hice el cambio agregando el foreach dentro de un @isset($destinos) y sigue el mismo error, creo que mi error es la manera como guardo el destino dentro del arreglo.

Comment: En principio veo que estás pisando los valores con `$array_destinos=$destino;`, pues si querés un array tendrías que `$array_destinos[] = $destino;` para que guarde cada destino en un elemento distinto del array

Comment: En mi controlador arriba creo el array asi. $array_destinos=array();

Comment: Si cuando declaras la variable le asignas como valor un array vacío, pero luego lo pisas asignando como valor un objeto `Destino`, por eso te digo que sería `$array_destinos[] = $destino; `

Comment: gracias esa era la solucion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a los comentarios del amigo [@porloscerros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92278/porloscerros-%CE%A8) realice los cambios en la manera como guardo el objeto destino en la variable tipo array llamada $array_destinos.
anteriormente estaba guardando de esta manera `$array_destinos=$destino;` la cual estaba mal ya que estaba sustituyendo todo el contenido de mi arreglo por el ultimo que entrara, si lo que quería era un array de objetos tendría que guardarlo de la siguiente manera `$array_destinos[]=$destino;`

```
    public function obtenerDestinos($idorigen)
{
    $destinos=App\Models\Protege\Destino::all();
    $array_destinos=array();

    if($idorigen==1)
    {
        foreach ($destinos as $destino)
        {
            if($destino->id!==4)
            {
                $array_destinos[]=$destino;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($destinos as $destino)
        {
            if($destino->id===4)
            {
                $array_destinos[]=$destino;
            }
        }
    }

    $view = View::make('select-destino')->with('destinos', $array_destinos)->render();
    return response()->json(['html' => $view]);
}
```